# Prevent abuse of web app through masked routing

Tags: php, laravel, server, request, httprequest

We created a web app with Laravel which provide some service.
Now, we noticed that there are some user which are doing abuse.
They have a user account resell it over their platform where all their user goes over that single user. In fact, they just route all request from https://their.platform.com/our-service to https://our.web-app.com/our-service.

First we could prevent with checking HTTP_HOST and HTTP_ORIGIN, but they found now a way to mask all. Sure, i could block their IPs, but then they just can change it.

How can i really prevent that?

Comment: With constant vigilance. Yes they can change their IP, so you have to keep monitoring it. It's a never-ending battle with this sort of thing, unfortunately. Also maybe you can impose things like rate limits so one account and/or IP can't make an unrealistic number of requests in a particular timescale, and/or you drastically increase the price for making large numbers of requests so it's not economic for them. You write some proper terms of service and get your lawyers onto it if they violate them. There are lots of things you can do, use your imagination a bit.